# Creating a Topojson file for a single state using make

Tags: geojson, shapefile, topojson

I'm trying to understand Bostock's ["lets make a bubble map tutorial"](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bubble-map/).

In particular, I'm hung on the following: When converting the shapefiles to Topojson files, Bostock sets the filter to none, so as to make a map of the entire U.S.

But what if we want to just make a map of one state? How should we set filter in the make file? (or should we do something else?)

Here is the code in question, from the makefile:

```
build/counties.json: build/gz_2010_us_050_00_20m.shp
    node_modules/.bin/topojson \
        -o $@ \
        --projection='width = 960, height = 600, d3.geo.albersUsa() \
            .scale(1280) \
            .translate([width / 2, height / 2])' \
        --simplify=.5 \
        --filter=none \
        -- counties=$<
```

I have also used the [Bostock make file](https://github.com/mbostock/us-atlas/blob/master/Makefile) and this command:

```
make shp/{state}/tracts.shp
```

It works but seems limiting?

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you apply a filter via the `STATE_FIPS` column inside the attribute table for that SHP file?